# get value of HTML element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I've made a stopwatch in JavaScript, and i'm showing it through h1 tag of HTML and i'm able to get it's textContent with following code in JS.

```
<h1 id="time">00:00:00</h1>    
var h1 = document.getElementById('time'),
         getTimer = h1.textContent;
```

Which fetches the value perfectly, but the problem is when i hit the start button to run the stopwatch and then if click getTime button it still fetches the static value of h1 tag that is 00:00:00, which is not what i'm looking for.I want to fetch the current value of h1 tag which is updating constantly.
Suppose i clicked on start button and then after 10sec if i click on getTime i want 00:00:10 as the value of getTimer variable but in my case it's showing only 00:00:00.

Here's the [working codepen](https://codepen.io/Kishan93/pen/rwPoap) demo for the same.

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById('time'),
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t,
  getTimer = document.getElementById('time').textContent,
  fetchVal = document.getElementById('fetchVal'),
  form = document.getElementById('form');

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  alert(getTimer);
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form">
 <h1 id="time">00:00:00</h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<button type="submit" id="fetchVal">Get Time</button>
</form>
```

How do i get the current value of h1 tag? I'm looking for solution in pure JS

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `getTimer = document.getElementById('time').textContent` is your page loaded value `00:00:00` ,so will always get that value !!! Should change `getTimer = document.getElementById('time')` and `alert(getTimer.textContent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fetch the new content of the DIV when the user clicks on the button.

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById('time'),
  start = document.getElementById('start'),
  stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
  clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
  seconds = 0,
  minutes = 0,
  hours = 0,
  t,
  getTimer = document.getElementById('time').textContent,
  fetchVal = document.getElementById('fetchVal'),
  form = document.getElementById('form');

function add() {
  seconds++;
  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

  timer();
}

function timer() {
  t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
  clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
  h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
}
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  getTimer = document.getElementById('time').textContent;
  alert(getTimer);
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form">
  <h1 id="time">00:00:00</h1>
  <button id="start">start</button>
  <button id="stop">stop</button>
  <button id="clear">clear</button>
  <button type="submit" id="fetchVal">Get Time</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see the issue with your problem. `getTimer` is a string and the value is created and locked in the first time the variable is created. Instead, you should defined `getTimer` as a function and invoke it with `getTimer()` instead of `getTimer`.

```
// very simple change
getTimer = function () { return document.getElementById('time').textContent },
```

Now the code *inside* the function will be run when the function is invoked like this: `getTimer()`

See the changed code below:

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById('time'),
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t,
    // change `getTimer` to be a function instead eargly grabbing the value
  getTimer = function () { return document.getElementById('time').textContent},
  fetchVal = document.getElementById('fetchVal'),
  form = document.getElementById('form');

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  alert(getTimer()); // now call the function instead just using the value
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form">
 <h1 id="time">00:00:00</h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<button type="submit" id="fetchVal">Get Time</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I will use innerHTML for getTimer**

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById('time'),
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t,
  getTimer = document.getElementById('time'),
  fetchVal = document.getElementById('fetchVal'),
  form = document.getElementById('form');

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  alert(getTimer.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form">
 <h1 id="time">00:00:00</h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<button type="submit" id="fetchVal">Get Time</button>
</form>
```